# maas ready node restarts

Tags: juju, maas, pxe

I don't really know what should happen after what. First I manually powered on a node and selected PXE boot through LAN. It acquired its IP. and started booting and then its installed ubuntu packages in curses based screens. I saw its status showing declared, then Ready. It appeared as green.

and then its got powered off automatically. I thought it will be restarted automatically. But that didn't happen. When I manually turned it on, this is what `pserv.log` reports:

```
Logged OOPS id OOPS-fe8038e88c0ed9cd0e4b6474041d4e32: No exception type: No exception value
2014-10-17 11:48:53+0530 [HTTPPageGetter,client] Logged OOPS id OOPS-38260ffcd5f216e137b810f1a3596a66: AssertionError: No PXE template found in u'/etc/maas/templates/pxe' for:
          Purpose: u'poweroff', Arch: u'amd64', Subarch: u'generic'
        This can happen if you manually power up a node when its state is not one that allows it. Is the node in the 'Declared' or 'Ready' states? It needs to be Enlisting, Commissioning or Allocated.
```

and node shuts down again. This is the second time I am recommissioning a node. However I have one other node ready and allocated to maas through juju. What is the way out.

Answer (score 0):

The next step is force node to commissioning, you can find Node pages as actions, it will power on the servers and commission it and power it off again.

after you install any service on that node it will power-on and ....